# Send bulk push notification from php server to android devices

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i am working on a app where there is need to send bulk push notification from the Php server to android devices . Is there any way to send multiple push notification from Php server to all devices  without using any Loop. 
*because this loop process reduce response time to client from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to send multiple push notification from Php server to all devices without using any Loop

[You can send a message to up to 1000 devices at a time](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#send-msg). If you need to send more than that, you will need a loop.

> because this loop process reduce response time to client from the server.

The time required by a loop will be minuscule compared the network time it takes for the communications to go from your server to the GCM servers, the time the messages are stored on the GCM servers, the network time for sending the messages from the servers to the devices, etc. The microseconds that the loop will require will be swamped by the seconds that the rest of the process takes.

Comment: Thanks a lot gentleman, Can you please give me code snippet . It will be more appropriated .